# Decimal value are missing

Tags: c#, google-maps

I stored the latitude and longitude value with decimal(18,15) in database.
Lat = 1.302208000000000
Long = 103.797717000000000

I would like to show the details of their values.
I used the decimal data type in service object.
decimal Lat, Long;

Here is my code.

```
ServiceTest test = new ServiceTest ();

//Method 1
test.Lat = Convert.ToDecimal(test1.Lat.ToString());
test.Long= Convert.ToDecimal(test1.Long.ToString());

//Method 2
test.Lat = (decimal)test1.Lat;
test.Long= (decimal)test1.Long;

// Method 3
test.Lat = decimal.Parse(test1.Lat.ToString());
test.Long= decimal.Parse(test1.Long.ToString());
```

I want the exact Lat,Long value.
But the results are:

```
test.Lat = 1.30
test.Long = 103.80
```

How can I get the results like:

```
test.Lat = 1.302208000000000
test.Long = 103.797717000000000
```

Thanks

Comment: Decimal is probably not a good data type for this. Float or double makes more sense.

Comment: 15 Decimal places?   Have you tapped into the NORAD GPS satellites?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I used double instead of decimal. It works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at this: [MSDN Decimal Formatting docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Basically, the toString method decides (in the absence of you telling it what format to print in) to truncate to two decimal places.  You can override this behavior using the linked format specifiers.

I also found this, might be helpful: [random google search for 'decimal format C#' produced this](http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/09/formatting-decimals-in-csharp/)